# Error propagation on GSL eigenvalues computation

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues, error-estimation

The problem comes from the need to estimate the error propagation of the [spectral norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm) computation of a square matrix $A$ of which I know the components' $A_{ij}$ absolute error.

The fundamental step of the computation of the spectral norm  $||A||_2$ is the computation of the largest eigenvalue of the matrix $A^TA$. In fact the spectral norm is defined as
$$||A||_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_\mathrm{max}(A^TA)}$$
where $\lambda_\mathrm{max}(A^TA)$ denotes the maximum eigenvalue of $A^TA$.

In my algorithm I'm using the GSL library to compute this $\lambda_\mathrm{max}$.
On it's [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Eigensystems.html) the GSL states that the algorithm used is a "*symmetric bidiagonalization followed by QR reduction*".

My question is: given the absolute error of the components $A_{ij}$ how can I estimate the error on the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$?
Can you point me on the direction to further investigate the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how deep you want to get into it, but you may want to check out Z. Bai's "Error Analysis of the Lanczos algorithm for the non-symmetric eigenvalue problem", [Math. Comp. 62 (1994), 209-226](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1994-62-205/S0025-5718-1994-1201066-7/). It is open access, so you can access it freely.

C.C. Paige's "Accuracy and effectiveness of the Lanczos algorithm for the symmetric eigenproblem", [Linear Algebra and its Applications, Volume 34, (1980), Pages 235-258](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379580901676), may be more appropriate, as it deals with symmetric problems.